# How to make Win + L work in Virtualbox guest OS when Windows 8 is a host?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, awesome-wm

I'm using Virtualbox on Windows 8 machine. My guest OS is Linux with Awesome WM. My problem is that my mod key is set to WIN. This causes problem with WIN + L, as it doesn't go to guest OS. It gets caught  by Windows and causes computer to lock. Is there any way to fix this or overcome? I know two solutions:

- disabling locking in windows - not an option for me
- use different key bindings by exchanging:

  - WIN key - but it is hard to find different key that wouldn't clash with vim
  - L key - but this works well with other vim navigation keys

Do you know any better approach towards this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Windows Key hotkeys when using Virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/121787/disable-windows-key-hotkeys-when-using-virtualbox)

Answer (score 0):

To pass **everything** to VirtualBox, I make sure that in the bottom right corner of the VM window, it looks like a down arrow filled in green. The key to activate it is written next to it, like this

[image: VirtualBox]

As you can see, the arrow is black. Press the key that is outlined next to it (Control_R) to make it green and pass everything to VirtualBox.

Comment: It didn't worked. It doesn't matter whether this is black or green as in either case WIN + L results in screen lock

Comment: After reading https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=32265 , Try Host+L

Comment: also no luck with it - it just sends L

Answer (score 0):

Do a one time disable of locking.

Write a program that does the following-
Reenable locking from registry
Lock computer
Disable locking

Map this to your favorite hot key

There is an ahk that does that- on phone so can't find